# R: read_csv ignores col_types

Tags: r, readr, vroom

I'm using *read_csv* to read in data while trying to ensure variables are read in as the correct type. To do so, I've first set up a "data dictionary", containing the mapping between variable names and their type (in "short" format: e.g., "d" for double, "c" for character, etc.) I've got code that gets the columns I want and the data types I expect them to be, but when I pass those values to the `col_select` and `col_types` arguments, it doesn't always work.

```
d1=tibble(read_var_2="2024-02-29",read_var_1="4",ignore_var_1="null",read_var_3="text")
write_csv(d1,"data_d1.csv")

test_d1 = read_csv(
  "data_d1.csv",
  col_select = c("read_var_2", "read_var_1", "read_var_3"),
  col_types = "Ddc"
)
test_d1 ## works as expected
# # A tibble: 1 × 3
#   read_var_2 read_var_1 read_var_3
#   <date>          <dbl> <chr>     
# 1 2024-02-29          4 text      

d2=tibble(read_var_2="2024-02-29",read_var_1="4",ignore_var_1="null",read_var_3="text",read_var_4="37.89")
write_csv(d2,"data_d2.csv")

test_d2 = read_csv(
  "data_d2.csv", 
  col_select = all_of(c("read_var_2", "read_var_1", "read_var_3", "read_var_4")),
  col_types = "Ddcd"
)

## PROBLEM
test_d2 ## why is read_var_3 NA dbl, it should be character "text"?
# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#   read_var_2 read_var_1 read_var_3 read_var_4
#   <date>          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2024-02-29          4         NA       37.9
```

Comment: Reading the `?read_csv` help page, the `col_types` description includes the line *"If you only want to read a subset of the columns, use `cols_only()`."* I wonder if there is an issue with `col_select` not playing well with `col_types`.

Comment: Your code is complex just to handle a dictionnary with missing values. You might want to use `dplyr::case_match`

`colnames(data_dict) %>% 
  case_match(
    "read_var_1" ~ "d",
  "read_var_2" ~ "D",
  "read_var_3" ~ "c",
  "read_var_4" ~ "d"
)`

Comment: I'm going to edit drastically to focus on the issue. I agree with Vince, your code is rather complex to get the col selections and types, but moreover that part of your code is working as expected--you get the values you want. So while that code could be simplified, it is not part of the problem. The issue is with `read_csv`, so I am going to delete your code to produce the inputs for `read_csv` and edit it down to the heart of the problem.

Comment: still new to R so my code tends to be hopelessly verbose... so thx for pointing out case_match, and breaking down the question to its core. but seems like at least I didn't hallucinate the problem...

Comment: You seems right about the weid interaction between `col_select()` and `col_types` With the edited example, `cols_only()` seems to work. 
`test_d2 = read_csv(
  "data_d2.csv", 
  col_select = c("read_var_2", "read_var_1", "read_var_3", "read_var_4"),
  col_types =  cols_only( read_var_2 = "D", 
                          read_var_1 ="d" ,
                          read_var_3 = "c",
                          read_var_4 = "d")
)` 

Other option: specifying to "skip" with `col_types = "Dd_cd"`.

Not easy to generalize

Comment: Using `type_convert` could be an additionnal tool (with or without argument).  `test_d2 = read_csv( "data_d2.csv") %>% 
  select( c("read_var_2", "read_var_1", "read_var_3", "read_var_4")) %>% 
  type_convert("Ddcd")`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. playing around I found the following works well for my use case: `df = read_csv(filepath, col_select=all_of(data_vars), col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>% type_convert(data_types)`. So explicitly reading in requested vars as character, both to prevent `read_csv` from guessing data type incorrectly and to ensure the input to `type_convert` is character-only (which it needs to be).